# How to use lemodev highscore plugin for unity?

Tags: c#, unity, leaderboards

I am trying to add a server-sided highscore system to my game in unity. I have downloaded the free lemodev highscore plugin from the asset store but I cant figure out how to use it. I know where to put my server info and so on but other what are you supposed to do ? I added the main camera prefab that came with the package to my scene but other than adding an additional camera it did precisely nothing ( at least it seems that way ). Could anyone look into it and tell me how to use it ? The developer's website seems to have no information on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like with almost ANY unity3d package there is a file called read me.txt. This is where the general use and how to is explained. This file can be found after importing the package in the folder  Assets/Highscore/readme. Pictures also seem to be included with this particular one

> 1. Import the package
> 2. Create database
> 3. Create table in database (use the file "create database table" - see picture 1)
> 4. Edit common.php (find them under PHP), use notepad or notepad++ to edit
>      Change Host to your database location (e.g. MySql.Example.com), 
>      Change User to your database login name
>      Change Pass to your database login password
>      Change Databasename to your database name
>      Change SecretKey to your secretKey in unity
>      (see picture 2)
> 5. Upload the PHP folder to your server (crossdomain.xml must be placed in the root folder)
> 6. Go to Highscore, choose Scene, open Highscore
> 7. Under Main Camera - Highscore Script, change variables
>
>    Secretkey must be the same as in the php script
>      Locate files on server. (Important: add a questionmark at the end)
>      Skin: you can keep the default or customize
>      Get limit score: the number of scores you get back

Source: read me file included in the package

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already figured this part by now though.